# JPQL query Exception unexpected AST node: {vector}

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

dears, I have a problem working with JPQL query, when I work with IN and a List(Long) I get an error, but no always

[this is the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSSpf.png)
(is minimal model for look the relationships, without all columns)

and if I do this query in mi repo works fine:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a FROM Artist a WHERE a.idArtist IN(SELECT a.idArtist FROM ArtistStyle x "
            + "INNER JOIN x.style s " 
            + "INNER JOIN x.artist a " 
            + "WHERE s.idStyle IN (:arrayStyles))")
    public List<Artist> FilterArtistWithStyles(List<Long> arrayStyles);
```

but if I do this query I get and error:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a FROM Artist a WHERE a.idArtist IN(SELECT a.idArtist FROM ArtistStyle x "
            + "INNER JOIN x.style s " 
            + "INNER JOIN x.artist a " 
            + "INNER JOIN a.country c " 
            + "INNER JOIN a.aal1 a1 "
            + "INNER JOIN a.aal2 a2 " 
            + "INNER JOIN a.aal3 a3 " 
            + "WHERE (:arrayStyles IS NULL OR s.idStyle IN (:arrayStyles)) "
            + "AND (:name IS NULL OR a.name like %:name%)" + "AND (:gender IS NULL OR a.gender = :gender) "
            + "AND (:experienceFrom IS NULL OR a.workStartYear <= :experienceFrom) "
            + "AND (:ratingFrom IS NULL OR a.ratingAccordance >= :ratingFrom) "
            + "AND (:delivery IS NULL OR a.delivery = :delivery) "
            + "AND (:exchange IS NULL OR a.exchange = :exchange) " + "AND (:courses IS NULL OR a.courses = :courses)"
            + "AND (:idCountry IS NULL OR c.idCountry = :idCountry)"
            + "AND (:idAal1 IS NULL OR a1.idAdministrativeAreaLevel1 = :idAal1)"
            + "AND (:idAal2 IS NULL OR a2.idAdministrativeAreaLevel2 = :idAal2)"
            + "AND (:idAal3 IS NULL OR a3.idAdministrativeAreaLevel3 = :idAal3)" + ")")
    public List<Artist> SearchArtistWithStyles(String name, List<Long> arrayStyles, Integer gender, Integer experienceFrom, Double ratingFrom, Integer delivery,
            Integer exchange, Integer courses, Long idCountry, Long idAal1, Long idAal2, Long idAal3,
            Pageable pageable);
```

this is the error:

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector} [SELECT a FROM com.mushroomstudios.skink.entities.Artist a WHERE a.idArtist IN(SELECT a.idArtist FROM com.mushroomstudios.skink.entities.ArtistStyle x INNER JOIN x.style s INNER JOIN x.artist a INNER JOIN a.country c INNER JOIN a.aal1 a1 INNER JOIN a.aal2 a2 INNER JOIN a.aal3 a3 WHERE (:arrayStyles_0, :arrayStyles_1, :arrayStyles_2 IS NULL OR s.idStyle IN (:arrayStyles_0, :arrayStyles_1, :arrayStyles_2)) AND (:name IS NULL OR a.name like :name)AND (:gender IS NULL OR a.gender = :gender) AND (:experienceFrom IS NULL OR a.workStartYear <= :experienceFrom) AND (:ratingFrom IS NULL OR a.ratingAccordance >= :ratingFrom) AND (:delivery IS NULL OR a.delivery = :delivery) AND (:exchange IS NULL OR a.exchange = :exchange) AND (:courses IS NULL OR a.courses = :courses)AND (:idCountry IS NULL OR c.idCountry = :idCountry)AND (:idAal1 IS NULL OR a1.idAdministrativeAreaLevel1 = :idAal1)AND (:idAal2 IS NULL OR a2.idAdministrativeAreaLevel2 = :idAal2)AND (:idAal3 IS NULL OR a3.idAdministrativeAreaLevel3 = :idAal3)) order by a.name asc]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector} [SELECT a FROM com.mushroomstudios.skink.entities.Artist a WHERE a.idArtist IN(SELECT a.idArtist FROM com.mushroomstudios.skink.entities.ArtistStyle x INNER JOIN x.style s INNER JOIN x.artist a INNER JOIN a.country c INNER JOIN a.aal1 a1 INNER JOIN a.aal2 a2 INNER JOIN a.aal3 a3 WHERE (:arrayStyles_0, :arrayStyles_1, :arrayStyles_2 IS NULL OR s.idStyle IN (:arrayStyles_0, :arrayStyles_1, :arrayStyles_2)) AND (:name IS NULL OR a.name like :name)AND (:gender IS NULL OR a.gender = :gender) AND (:experienceFrom IS NULL OR a.workStartYear <= :experienceFrom) AND (:ratingFrom IS NULL OR a.ratingAccordance >= :ratingFrom) AND (:delivery IS NULL OR a.delivery = :delivery) AND (:exchange IS NULL OR a.exchange = :exchange) AND (:courses IS NULL OR a.courses = :courses)AND (:idCountry IS NULL OR c.idCountry = :idCountry)AND (:idAal1 IS NULL OR a1.idAdministrativeAreaLevel1 = :idAal1)AND (:idAal2 IS NULL OR a2.idAdministrativeAreaLevel2 = :idAal2)AND (:idAal3 IS NULL OR a3.idAdministrativeAreaLevel3 = :idAal3)) order by a.name asc]",
```

finally, if I do that query, works fine too:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a FROM Artist a " + "INNER JOIN a.country c " 
            + "INNER JOIN a.aal1 a1 "
            + "INNER JOIN a.aal2 a2 " 
            + "INNER JOIN a.aal3 a3 " 
            + "WHERE (:name IS NULL OR a.name like %:name%) "
            + "AND (:gender IS NULL OR a.gender = :gender) "
            + "AND (:experienceFrom IS NULL OR a.workStartYear <= :experienceFrom) "
            + "AND (:ratingFrom IS NULL OR a.ratingAccordance >= :ratingFrom) "
            + "AND (:delivery IS NULL OR a.delivery = :delivery) "
            + "AND (:exchange IS NULL OR a.exchange = :exchange) " + "AND (:courses IS NULL OR a.courses = :courses)"
            + "AND (:idCountry IS NULL OR c.idCountry = :idCountry)"
            + "AND (:idAal1 IS NULL OR a1.idAdministrativeAreaLevel1 = :idAal1)"
            + "AND (:idAal2 IS NULL OR a2.idAdministrativeAreaLevel2 = :idAal2)"
            + "AND (:idAal3 IS NULL OR a3.idAdministrativeAreaLevel3 = :idAal3)")
    public List<Artist> SearchArtist(String name, Integer gender, Integer experienceFrom, Double ratingFrom,
            Integer delivery, Integer exchange, Integer courses, Long idCountry, Long idAal1, Long idAal2, Long idAal3,
            Pageable pageable);
```

there are something bad in the second query? If you need more info like entity or other thing please let me know, thanks in advance

Comment: Idk if that is the cause but you are reusing `a` alias

Comment: Offtopic: `a.name like %:name%` is a performance killer.

Comment: thanks, but I thought that if I used (:name IS NULL OR a.name like %:name%) only executes the like if :name value is not null, and I set name null if user do not type nothing. In that way is a performance killer anyway? can I replace with other way?

Comment: it name is null than this clause is out - but if it is not - you will have non-indexed whole table match search.

Answer (score 2):

problem was in this line

```
 "WHERE (:arrayStyles IS NULL OR s.idStyle IN (:arrayStyles)) "
```

I changed to, and works fine

```
+ "WHERE s.idStyle IN (:arrayStyles) "
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a work around, creating a Boolean if the List has elements:

...

`Boolean shouldValidateList = someList != null && !someList().isEmpty();`

...

`"Where :shouldValidateList = false or FieldInQuestion IN :someList"`

Ps. In my case I had other filters in "where" condition, just the "IN" didn't work for me. But if it is the only filter, just "IN" works perfectly